# Jenkins Pipeline Syntax for "p4sync"

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to sync to Perforce in my pipeline script, but from the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/p4/#p4sync-p4-sync) I don't see a way to set the "workspace behavior", even though the plugin itself seems to have [that capability](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/p4/workspace).

I want the "workspace" to be equivalent to the setting "Manual (custom view)" I can configure in the UI as described [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/SETUP.md#workspaces). What parameters do I need to pass to the `p4sync` task to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to use the full `checkout` DSL, the `p4sync` DSL is only basic. The easiest way is to use the snippet generator (*Pipeline Syntax* link), select `checkout: General SCM` then `Perforce Software` from the SCM list.

You will then be able to define a detailed View.  For example:

```groovy
checkout([
  $class: 'PerforceScm', 
  credential: 'phooey1666', 
  populate: [
    $class: 'AutoCleanImpl', 
    delete: true, 
    modtime: false, 
    pin: '', 
    quiet: true, 
    replace: true
  ], 
  workspace: [
    $class: 'ManualWorkspaceImpl', 
    charset: 'none', 
    name: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}', 
    pinHost: false, 
    spec: [
      allwrite: true, 
      clobber: false, 
      compress: false, 
      line: 'LOCAL', 
      locked: false, 
      modtime: false, 
      rmdir: false, 
      streamName: '',
      view: '''
        //depot/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}/...
        -//depot/tests/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}/tests/...'''
    ]
  ]
])
```

Comment: Presumably this syncs the entire view.   Is there a way to separate specifying the mapping from the set of files to be checked out?  For example - we have a many large depots, and each project knows what it needs.  So if we could specify a simple high level mapping we can let the build do the syncing.  Otherwise we either map+sync far too much, or map+sync based on the project - duplicating information and increasing maintainance. (comment 5 min rule)

Comment: With a ManualWorkspace the View (map+sync) is your only, you could add multiple `checkout` step in your pipeline or delegate some to a Groovy library.  Just remember that you must use different workspace names for multiple `checkout` steps.

Comment: Streams may work better in a 'project' environment as each child will inherit the view from it's parent, saving the duplication of complex mappings.  The Jenkins `p4-plugin` supports streams in ManualWorkspaceImpl and in StreamsWorkspaceImpl depending on how much control you need.

Comment: Streams seem like a good options - although I'll have to persuade the large legacy projects that I'm trying the Jenkify to adopt them.

Comment: This view definition would not work because of leading spaces, but adding `stripIndent()` to the view string may be all that is needed.